# How to grant temporary permissions to user?

Tags: django

In my application I want the user to re-enter their password before being able to complete a sensitive action such as editing their subscription. After successfully re-authenticating the permissions would be time-limited.

I can't find django functionality that enables this, but since django seems to do just about everything else I thought it worth asking - can django do this or can it be configured to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an explicit permission. The [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/) is ideal for setting temporary attributes on a user.

For instance, when the user re-auths you could add a timestamp:

```
request.session['reauth_at'] = datetime.datetime.now()
```

and check it in the edit subscription view:

```
earliest_reauth = datetime.datetime.now() - REAUTH_EXPIRY_DURATION
if request.session.get('reauth_at', datetime.datetime.min) > earliest_reauth:
    ... allow ...
```

Comment: Thanks again Daniel!